# Using django-compressor with render_block from sekizai_tags

Tags: django, django-templates, django-compressor, django-sekizai

I would like to be able to

1. Compile all js/css into single minified files, which is what [`django-compressor`](https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor) does.
2. Be able to add js/css files from included and inherited templates.

When I try:

```
{% compress css file %}
{% render_block "css" %}
{% endcompress %}
```

I get the error: `Invalid block tag: 'endcompress'`

But I think the main cause is from the [sekizai docs](http://django-sekizai.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#restrictions):

> `{% render_block %}` tags must not be placed inside a template tag block (a template tag which has an end tag, such as `{% block %}...{% endblock %}` or `{% if %}...{% endif %}`).

Have I done something wrong or is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

It seems [django-compressor explicitly provides this interaction](http://django-compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django-sekizai/#usage), but not by putting `render_block` inside `compress/endcompress`:

> ```
> {% load sekizai_tags %}
> {% render_block "<js/css>" postprocessor "compressor.contrib.sekizai.compress" %}
> ```

In fact, the `{% compress %}` tag is simply not used here.

```
<head>
...
<!-- css -->
{% render_block "css" postprocessor "compressor.contrib.sekizai.compress" %}
{% block css %}{% endblock %}
<!-- end js -->
...
</head>

... then in another template ...

{% block css %}
{% addtoblock "css" %}
    {{ form.media.css }}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..." />
{% endaddtoblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

I use `block css` just for the sake of having any block to put `addtoblock` in, otherwise it won't work (unless it's in the same template file):

> If the `{% addtoblock %}` tag is used in an extending template, the tags must be placed within `{% block %}...{% endblock %}` tags.